Was the Web Apps SE moderator team consulted about the AI "Answer Bot" experiment?
The recent Meta SE post, "What is 'Answer Bot' and what is it doing?" has Philippe, SE's VP of Community, explaining that the "Answer Bot" (an AI powered by SE's LLM partners, which has been creating hidden posts on Web Apps SE) was part of a limited test with moderators:

In this current stage, we’ll show some of the functionality and content to the moderators of those sites to get initial feedback. Last week, we released a brief test for moderators on a few question pages on Web Applications, and we’re investigating why some elements became visible beyond the moderators of those sites.


Due to the sensitivity around LLM content in the broader SE community, we were intentional about our desire to do some further testing with mods who are open to considering the test before talking about this experiment more broadly. However, with the complexity of the platform and the novelty of “non-public” states for content, it proved difficult to keep all aspects of this viewable only to moderators.

This implies that the Web Apps SE moderator team (or at least some members of it) consented to this experiment. However, I'd like to clarify: Did the Web Apps SE moderator team actually agree to participate in this test? If not the whole team, was there at least one moderator who agreed? Or was this experiment implemented by Stack Exchange without the moderator team's prior agreement?

I appreciate your question.

I was consulted about testing LLM for this site. The initial phase involved reviewing sample AI-generated content to see the quality of the responses and viability of this model.
I started a new job during the process and have not yet completed that initial review as I became buried in work and the AI responses were long-winded and each delivered in a spreadsheet cell with markdown. I gave SE this feedback.
SE subsequently implemented a test release on the site that was intended to allow mods a way to review sample responses in a more normalized way. This wasn't supposed to impact site users, but to get initial feedback on the model and allow mods to see if it provided benefits and warranted presenting to the wider community for further discussion.
I didn't explicitly agree to installing the test release on the site, nor did I register any objections.  SE communicated their desire to implement it in the mod-only chat and I was not pinged on those messages (chat $%#$) and because of my workload I did not see them until today, as a result of your post.
Regarding AI, on the face of it I'm open to anything that improves the community and has the community's support. From a tech nerd standpoint I was interested to see the real world performance of AI, particularly for problems that amounted to documentation searches. Recent experiences trying to leverage AI myself have lowered my expectations, but I reserve judgement.
Apparently SE's implementation of the test release was flawed and exposed to site users outside of mods. My understanding is that whatever they accidentally stepped on has now been tidied up.
Given what transpired, I will follow up with the community earlier with my feedback on the tests.

I see, and I appreciate the detailed response. Just to clarify, did the rest of the moderator team also not explicitly agree to the test release being installed on the site, or were there others who were more involved in the decision?

there's a few specific things here that feel wrong - the lack of confirmation via pings/superpings, and the initial format of "here's a giant, unusable spreadsheet"

Their failure to use chat effectively and get acknowledgement is bad, but “okay let’s put these in the real sure UI for better evaluation” seems like a good response to being told their spreadsheet is unusable, and might not indicate that it was meant to be used “live” “for real” as immediately as people were assuming.

@JourneymanGeek I don't see the pings/superpings issue as intentional omission but reflects structural problems with the chat app, and the way it manages multiple threads.  I am as guilty of missing a ping here and there as others. As a tech person we may have better instincts for when we step over the "here there be dragons" line that business folk, and situations like the current one are the reason.

@Jeremy I see this in that light. From SE's perspective they are trying to put their best foot forward. If the experience for testers is like putting a fork in their eye, then it's understandable why they would add bells and whistles to improve the review process. I can't speak to the testing options and limitations of the current infrastructure.

@JourneymanGeek "there's a few specific things here that feel wrong" This AI thing is an onion and in the context of this layer (my conversations) I don't have feelings of "wrong" per se. I think that the spirit of what SE did was in keeping with the tone of our conversations and the feedback they were getting. It was obviously poorly implemented.
